# What's the difference between these two async methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

So I'm learning about async/await in C#, I made a small Windows forms app to just play with async/await. I came up with these:

Here is the `button1_Click` that's used for the two methods below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetSiteAsync();
    }
```

and here is the look of the app:

[image]

Method 1:

```
    public async void GetSiteAsync()
    {
        HttpClient ht = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> getTaskString = ht.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");

        label1.Text = "Loading...";

        string siteString = await getTaskString;

        label1.Text = "Finished! Site Length = " + siteString.Length;
    }
```

Method 2:

```
public async void GetSiteAsync()
{
    HttpClient ht = new HttpClient();
    string siteString = await ht.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");

    label1.Text = "Loading...";

    label1.Text = "Finished! Site Length = " + siteString.Length;
}
```

In the first method when i click on 'Load URL' button, it changes the label to 'Waiting...' and when loading is finished it changes it to 'Finished!' with the site length appended to it.

In the second method when I click on the button it doesn't change the label and when operation is completed it changes the label to the site length.

I noticed that both methods **don't** cause the program GUI to freez while loading the website.

So Why does second method fail to change the button to 'Loading...'??

Comment: You could "fix" the second method simply moving the line that sets the label to loading before the line that awaits the site string.

Comment: @juharr, Good point. But which way is recommended??

Comment: Worth noting that it's generally considered bad practice to use a return type of void when writing async methods. Instead the return type should be Task. The compiler will see the async keyword and behave the same as if it were a void return type

Comment: @simonlchilds Initially I was returning a Task but Visual Studio 2015 was giving warnings about `button1_Click` not having `async` modifier and I didn't want to edit the auto generated event handler.

Comment: await simply means "Wait! wait for me, i have to finish first then other things will happen"..

Comment: (I'm a web app guy so don't know) could you also change the signature of the button click to async Task too?

Comment: @simonlchilds You can mark the button private async void button_Click(...

Comment: @simonlchilds, I could add `async` modifier to button1_Click and then add `await` before calling `GetSiteAsync()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code after an `await` operator is executed after the call in the `await` have been completed. This may be done in another thread. In the background a state machine is created and we say that the code after the `await` would be executed in a continuation.

So in the first case,

```
Task<string> getTaskString = ht.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
label1.Text = "Loading...";
```

You just make an asynchronous call and then you set the `Text` value of the `label1`.

While in the second case,

```
string siteString = await ht.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");
label1.Text = "Loading...";
```

you `await` this call. This means that after the completion of this asynchrnous call, the setter of the `label1.Text` would be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The second method immediately jumps to the `label1.Text = "Finished! Site Length = " + siteString.Length;` line after the `label1.Text = "Loading...";` line, so you never actually see it.  The first method, you see it, because the await happens **after**.

So: 
First method: "loading" -> await -> "Finished!"
Second method: await -> "loading" -> "Finished!"

The "loading" is immediately written over in the second method.

Answer (score 1):

In the first method you set the label test to loading and then `await` the task.

In the second method you `await` the task (meaning you don't continue executing the rest of the code in the method until it's already done) and *then* you set the label to loading (and then set it to done immediately afterward).

The methods don't block the UI thread because they're asynchronous; they return control to the calling code very quickly, and continue to do work after yielding control.